# Альтернативы функций python на node js

Tags: python, node.js, base64, hex, bytearray

Какие есть альтернативы python функциям

```py
base64.b64decode("SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==")
# b'Hello, World!'

bytes.fromhex("01")
# b'\x01'
```

на node?
Нужно чтобы функции возвращали идентичные данные.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end

Comment: Только надо понимать что никаких бинарных строк в nodejs нет. Так что второй пример скорее должен остаться просто буфером, а первый комбинацией из from и toString